# Okta API returning an incomplete list of users and applications

Tags: okta, okta-api

I'm trying to fetch a list of all applications on Okta, and a list of the users using each application.

However, sending a GET request to /api/v1/apps is resulting in an incomplete list of applications, and following a link to the users of each app is also incomplete.

Am I calling incorrectly? Or is there some reason that specific apps/users would not show up in the list?

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am setting limit=10000 and still am missing users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a response exceeds the the maximum number of results, the results are paginated and a [`Link` header](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/design_principles.html#link-header) is added to the results.

For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Link: <https://yoursubdomain.okta.com/api/v1/users?after=00ubfjQEMYBLRUWIEDKK>; rel="next"  <https://yoursubdomain.okta.com/api/v1/users?after=00ub4tTFYKXCCZJSGFKM>; rel="self"
```

**Note:**  It is important to follow these `Link` header values instead of constructing your own URLs as query parameters or cursor formats may change without notice.

See the Okta documentation for [pagination](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/getting_started/design_principles.html#pagination) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I use the limit and after parameter.  Here is an example (in my code I increment my counter by the limit value)

{{url}}/api/v1/users?search=status eq "ACTIVE"and lastUpdated gt "2017-04-26T04:00:00.000Z" and created lt "2017-04-26T04:00:00.000Z" &limit=200&after=1400

This query will return any users that meet the criteria and are after 1400.  In other words if I have 1500 users it will return the users 1401 to 1500.

Comment: I highly suggest implement pagination using the URLs in the Link header instead of manually incrementing the value as Okta may change the way that pagination is implemented.